# Flex: Cannot tab between controls on a modal popup

Tags: apache-flex, popup, flex4, modal-dialog

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a modal popup to popup with popupmanager (mine is a group with a skinnable container inside of it)
2. Put field components (textinputs) on the modal popup
3. Attempt to tab between controls

Tab switches to controls behind the modal-popup and ignores the fact that the modal is there. The tab loop only contains controls behind the modal.

I've tried everything from setting tabChildren, to hasFocusableChildren. I can't implement IFocusManager as it's Halo and my modal is a Spark group, but would that work in some capacity? It really seems like Flex just ignores the modal in its focusmanager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug, I'm assuming it's by design.

Group is supposed to be a lightweight container -- just for grouping things together.  Group does not implement the IFocusManagerContainer interface.

SkinnableContainer (or more correctly SkinnableContainerBase) implements that interface, and that's why tabbing works when you use it w/PopupManager.

Answer (score 1):

Solution can be found here (if you want to use a Group):

http://googolflex.com/?p=650

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using TitleWindow instead of group with a skinnable container? We use TitleWindow all the time and it does tab correctly.

Comment: Using spark components as we're using Flex 4. I will try to take off the skinnablecontainer, and maybe try a titlewindow, and will let you know the results of the experiments.

Comment: Using Flex 4? Shouldn't you submit a bug report since it's not been released yet?

Comment: Update: FIXED (kinda). This is solely due to the fact that my root component is a s:Group. I changed it to a SkinnableContainer and had no more problems tabbing. I'd prefer to figure out how to use a Group in this capacity, but for now, a skinnablecontainer will do.